# Key to get help about current function

Tags: keyboard, documentation

I know you can hit <kbd>F1</kbd> to pop up the documentation center, and then type the name of a function and search for it.

I'd like to know if there's a key that just pops up the help page of the function the cursor is in right now.

For instance, when writing `Integrate[`, sometimes I forget the right syntax for it, so I just want to immediately see the help page for it without having to manually search for it.

Comment: You can right click the function and select 'Get Help'

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) [`Read the FAQs`](http://tinyurl.com/cacvex2)!  3) When you see good Q&A, vote them up by [`clicking the gray triangles`](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.  ALSO, remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [`by clicking the checkmark sign`](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)`

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov Don't worry, I will. I just like giving it a day or so before accepting an answer.

Comment: @BruceConnor This video provides a brief overview how to use the Suggestions Bar : http://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/video.php?channel=108&video=1340

Comment: This is just a standard greeting we post here for newcomers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is the same F1 key. If the cursor is anywhere **in the name of the function** adjacent to any function-name letter, then pressing F1 will bring the corresponding function documentation page.

[image]

Mathematica 9 [**Context-Sensitive Input Assistant**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/UsingTheInputAssistant.html) (or see [**this video**](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-9/context-sensitive-input-assistant/)) provide a set of useful options. For example this will appear as you type and clicking red-circled icon will also bring corresponding function documentation article:

[image]

BTW @ChrisDegnen is right about Control+Shift K, or Cmd+Shift K. But those key combinations or clicking this little triangle under function

[image]

will bring neat template syntax list right under function name in Mathematica 9:

[image]

Read up on the scope of Mathematica 9 [**Predictive Interface here**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/WolframPredictiveInterface.html).

Comment: I see. the reason it wasn't working for me is that I was hitting F1 after the openning bracket =) (which is how I did it in matlab). That'e exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Wait, when was this version 9 released? I bought my student license barely two weeks ago and I was only offered version 8.

Comment: @BruceConnor Very recently - [November 28, 2012](http://blog.wolfram.com/2012/11/28/mathematica-9-is-released-today/)

Comment: @BruceConnor -- If you just got your license it should allow you to upgrade to V9

Comment: @Jagra I'm contacting customer service, but the website is asking for a £50 purchase.

Answer (score 9):

You may also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to insert a template with the basic syntax already filled in with named placeholders.

[image]